# ORA-12516 Issue with ojdbc in Intellij

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea, ojdbc

I have a strange behaviour happening in one of our projects and I wonder if anyone encountered anything similar. It is a legacy Java project and we are using ojdbc6.jar to connect to an Oracle DB. Locally we are using a Tomcat 6 app server.
When using IntelliJ IDE the db connection fails in some cases (specially where higher number or more complicated queries are run), with

```
ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack
```

The strange thing is, that Eclipse users never have the mentioned problem. (For some reason, their db calls seem much faster too)
We are using an IBM Websphere JDK because of production reasons, its a 64 bit 1.8 jdk.
The issue happens more often when running debug, but also happens while running normally.
I looked up this error and tried the following things:

- monitored the number of processes oracle is running, but we have a limit of 400 and it never went above 300
- tried changing locally to ojdbc7 and ojdbc8: 7 produces the same issues, 8 throws a could not establish connection with Network Adapter error at the same situation
- tried changing the jdk-s under tomcat: no effect
- tried all kinds of memory settings for tomcat and for intellij, no effect

It's a pretty annoying issue and I dont understand, why this does not happen with Eclipse.

Thank you for your advice in advance!

Comment: Can you tell us more about the database? Is it a common database to all users (Eclipse and IntelliJ)? Or is it a local development database? XE? Which version?

Comment: It is a common DB for all developers, its an Oracle EE, 12.2.0.1.0.

Comment: do you use Database Tools and SQL plugin to connect to database or it is performed from Java code?

Comment: You mentioned that the db calls appear to be faster on Eclipse, are these calls SQL calls or connection creation?

Comment: Yuri: The calls are performed from Java, the connection is estabilished through a jndi utility, but its basicly just passing the connection string (same for everyone)
Jean: these are sql calls